# Pressing play / pause button on timer rapidly is making timer count down twice as fast. Wondering how to mend logic

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a simple countdown text that is paused/played with a button. It starts at the number of seconds passed down to the widget and counts down. My issue is when I press the pause / play button quickly the timer starts counting down faster. I'm guessing this is because the toggleTimer() method that runs when the button is pressed multiple times is triggering two instances of the timer periodic function. How can I mend this logic?

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:quickrest/styles/text_styles.dart';
import 'package:quickrest/styles/color_styles.dart';
import 'package:liquid_progress_indicator/liquid_progress_indicator.dart';

class ActiveTimerScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const ActiveTimerScreen({super.key, required this.seconds});

  final int seconds;

  @override
  State<ActiveTimerScreen> createState() => _ActiveTimerScreenState();
}

class _ActiveTimerScreenState extends State<ActiveTimerScreen> {
  int _timeLeft = 0;
  bool timerStarted = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _timeLeft = widget.seconds;
    /// Have timer start by default.
    timerStarted = true;
    toggleTimer();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            const SizedBox(width: double.infinity),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.3,
              ),
              child: Text(
                '${_timeLeft ~/ 60} : ${(_timeLeft % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}',
                style: activeTimerTitleTextStyle,
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                top: 80.0,
              ),
              child: ElevatedButton(
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  shape: const CircleBorder(),
                  backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    if (timerStarted) {
                      timerStarted = false;
                    } else {
                      timerStarted = true;
                      toggleTimer();
                    }
                  });
                },
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                  child: Icon(
                    !timerStarted ? Icons.play_arrow : Icons.pause,
                    size: 100,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 80.0),
              child: OutlinedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
                style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                  side: const BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                      Radius.circular(24),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                child: const Text(
                  "Cancel",
                  style: activeTimerCancelTextStyle,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void toggleTimer() {
    const oneSec = Duration(seconds: 1);
    Timer.periodic(oneSec, (Timer t) {
      if (_timeLeft < 1 || timerStarted == false) {
        t.cancel();
      } else {
        setState(() {
          _timeLeft = _timeLeft - 1;
        });
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: `toggleTimer` doesn't toggle anything. It just makes an additional timer every time it is called. You are getting the effect of several timers running simultaneously

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are starting different Timers that then independently do multiple times per second:

```
_timeLeft = _timeLeft - 1;
```

If you add in your _ActiveTimerScreenState a

```
Timer? _timer;
```

and then your toggleTimer method should look something like this:

```
void toggleTimer() {
    const oneSec = Duration(seconds: 1);
    _timer?.cancel();
    _timer = Timer.periodic(oneSec, (Timer t) {
      if (_timeLeft < 1) {
        t.cancel();
      } else {
        setState(() {
          _timeLeft = _timeLeft - 1;
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

it will not launch different Timers.

Also, in reality you are not using toggleTimer to toggle; you are only using it to launch new timers (you are only calling it when timerStarted is false). You might want to rename it to something like launchNewTimer.
You could also then stop/cancel your old Timer when the button is pressed:

```
onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    if (timerStarted) {
                      timerStarted = false;
                      _timer?.cancel();
                    } else {
                      timerStarted = true;
                      toggleTimer();
                    }
                  });
```